# undo two most recent commits

Tags: git

I want to undo the two most recent commits. These commits have already been pushed to the remote repo, but I suppose once I've undone them locally, I can push again, again they will effectively be undone in the remote repo.

I have the hashes for these commits, so what command do I need to run to undo them?

Comment: It's unclear to me why the answer hasn't been accepted; can you elaborate on what's missing?

Comment: I'd assume you do, but you've been on the site since November, and you're notified when there's activity on your questions. I don't really see a need to be sarcastic, I just believe that being a good SO citizen is important. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
git revert HEAD~2
```

Using `git help revert` will give you more details.

If you have pending changes in your working directory, stash before and unstash after.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get rid of the commits:

```
git checkout <branch>
git reset --hard <commit before the two commits>
git push <remote> +<branch>
```

The `+` makes a forced push.

You can use `HEAD^^` to refer to the commit just before the last two.

Edit: `git revert` is a way to undo the commits without removing them from the history. It is useful when the changes have been pulled by other people.

Comment: Don't do that if you work in a team and coworkers might have pulled. You would be hated by them. Changesets that have been pushed should generally not be altered.